# Responsive jQuery slider with scale ruler, start and end point will change dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, responsive-design

I want to add a scale-ruler below the Jquery slider where the start and endpoint should be changeable and slider should point to the exact number of the scale ruler, division between each number/point should have equal space in the scale ruler.

In this example the Starting point is 73 and endpoint 91, we can also change the start and endpoint.

[slider example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hd55.jpg)
based on the min and max values, I created the scale ruler(numbers) but it's not matching with the Jquery slider

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider();
  createSlider();

  function createSlider() {
    $("#scale-ruler").html("");
    let sliderHtml = "";
    let i;
    let min = lft = 0;
    let max = 30;

    for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        sliderHtml = sliderHtml + "<div style='left:" + i + "%' class='scale n5s s" + i + "'><span>" + i + "</span></div>";
      } else {
        sliderHtml = sliderHtml + "<div style='left:" + i + "%' class='scale s s" + i + "'></div>";
      }
    }
    $("#scale-ruler").html(sliderHtml);
  }
});
```

```css
.slider-Parent {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#scale-ruler {
  width: 100%;
  margin: -2px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  left: 2px;
}

#scale-ruler div.scale {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  top: -1px;
}

#scale-ruler div.n5s::after {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}

#scale-ruler div.scale::after {
  content: "\007C";
  font-size: 13px;
  top: -3.6px;
  position: relative;
}

#scale-ruler div.n5s span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="slider-Parent">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="scale-ruler"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem here is your `i` 'cause in your example is a number starting from 0 to 30. And you are transforming this number in a percentual (i.e. from 0% to 30%) and you need an expression to transform it from 0% to 100%.

So, a solution could be to use an expression like this:

```
perCent*(100/(max-min))
```

Where your perCent is a number starting from 0 to your max number (i.e. `max - min` number).

Ok, maybe it seems complicated, but with code becomes more simple to understand, I hope.

I tried to use your code with very little change, to help you to understand what's going on.

In addition to this, I added min & max options to jquery slider. 
In my code I recreated your jpg example.
(I change a little your CSS, but only to make it more precise with scale ruler, but well, it's only my opinion, you can use also yours).

```js
$(function() {
  let min = 73
  let max = 91;

  $("#slider").slider({
    min:min,
    max:max
  });

  createSlider();

  function createSlider() {
    $("#scale-ruler").html("");
    let sliderHtml = "";

    let perCent=0;

    for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        sliderHtml = sliderHtml + "<div style='left:" + perCent*(100/(max-min)) + "%' class='scale n5s s" + i + "'><span>" + i + "</span></div>";
      } else {
        sliderHtml = sliderHtml + "<div style='left:" + perCent*(100/(max-min)) + "%' class='scale s s" + i + "'></div>";
      }
      perCent++
    }
    $("#scale-ruler").html(sliderHtml);
  }


  $("#slider" ).slider("value", 74 ); /* this is only an example to put the slider to 74. You can remove it.*/
});
```

```css
.slider-Parent {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#scale-ruler {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
}

#scale-ruler div.scale {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  color: #ccc;
  top: -1px;
}

#scale-ruler div.n5s::after {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

#scale-ruler div.scale::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#scale-ruler div.scale:last-child::after {
  left: -1px;
}

#scale-ruler div.n5s span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="slider-Parent">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="scale-ruler"></div>
</div>
```